# server freezes whe trying to generate pdf with wicked pdf with wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

Im using

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge', '~> 0.12.4.0'
```

to generate pdf on a rails app. However whenever I try to generate pdf from my view, my development server freezes with the following log :

```
"***************[\"/Users/davidgeismar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/wkhtmltopdf\", \"-q\", \"file:////var/folders/vj/lv7d5nzn24s5sqgrtgxv92yw0000gn/T/wicked_pdf20181011-11803-1h7cvd1.html\", \"/var/folders/vj/lv7d5nzn24s5sqgrtgxv92yw0000gn/T/wicked_pdf_generated_file20181011-11803-77q39c.pdf\"]***************"
```

I followed [this thread](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/110) and tried several :
1) launching server on  127.0.0.1:3000 instead of localhost:3000 with  rails server -b 127.0.0.1

2) config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'
3)config.middleware.use WickedPdf::Middleware in application.rb

nothing works. Do you know anyways how to fix this ? My local machine is macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) Attempt to render a really basic view ("Hello World"); 2) have the view rendered as HTML (with the `show_as_html` option), save the HTML to disk, run it through wkhtmltopdf on the command line. These have helped me in the past when trying to figure out issues with wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: @david Did you solve this? Having similar issue